# I'm looking for an old kids show, I can't remember the name

Tags: story-identification, tv

This is driving me crazy, I know it's an old kids show, but all I can remember about it is that one or two of the characters sang La La La La La ... la! And there was all this mail that would come through the roof and they would read letters. And it think that the characters were either people in suits or puppets. I know that's not much to go on, but if anyone knows what this show is, I would be super happy.
The show was also super colorful, and I think there was a yellow house with a purple roof, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: In roughly which year did you watch this? And can you specify any sci-fi or fantasy elements within the show?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not appear to be about science fiction or fantasy

Comment: A huge proportion of kids' shows features magic or aliens.

Comment: Opposing closure.  It's almost certainly "Banana Splits" which had some SF segments.

Comment: @PastychomperthanksMonica - And those would be on-topic. But a show with no obvious fantasy elements would be off-topic

Comment: Hi Mirri, you may want to take the [tour].

Comment: @fez also without more details this is throwing papers at the wall and seeing which one sticks.

Comment: Voting to reopen. The identification of the Banana Splits is likely the right answer.  This had some SF segments including The Arabian Knights

Answer (score 1):

Could you be thinking of [*The Banana Splits*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Banana_Splits) (1968-70)?

The [theme tune](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XMl6HnhFFIA) had quite a lot of "*Tra la la*". You can see Episode 1 [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tf7Hd8npPUU), with mail-reading a few minutes in.

[image]

Comment: I don't see the mail falling from the sky. Also I'm not seeing a yellow house with a purple roof

Comment: I'm not putting this as an answer because I can't find any decent links for info. There was an obscure kids show in the mid 1970s called "The Yellow House" and kids read out requests for clips/cartoons that had been mailed in. I can't remember if they came through the roof. Do you recall a clown at the end? It ended every week with the kids singing about "we've all been to the yellow House" and that seems to fit your la la tempo. I remember the clown stood outside the house crying and wringing gallons out of his hankie. I can't remember the roof colour

Answer (score -1):

Could you be thinking of Teletubbies? The original series ran from 1997 to 2001 and a reboot of the series ran from 2014 to 2018. The show was aimed towards very young children so the show used a lot of bright primary colors. There was a pink house with a purple roof, and there also was a sort of underground home for the teletubbies that had a yellow ceiling. It also had simple phrases and a lot of repetition.

There were four members in the cast, Laa-Laa, Dipsy, Tinky-Winky and Po. The actors playing them were in full body costumes, like what you would see at a theme park. There is a definite resemblance to puppets. I’m not sure about mail coming from the ceiling, but you defiantly would hear the cast’s names often, including Laa-Laa’s.

[image: Po, Laa-Laa, Dispy and Tinky-Winky]

Overall it was inoffensive television aimed at young children, annoying only parents that had to watch it over and over and over again with their kids.

Except for the time when Jerry Falwell (a US Televangelist) thought that Tinky-Winky was corrupting young children into a homosexual lifestyle because he carried a bag that looked like a purse.

Comment: Oh no! Are we now in an age where people don't know/remember Telletubbies? Please, how do we stop this relentless passage of time?

Comment: @Darren - The answer is *'endless re-runs'* and *'endless shitty reboots'*

Comment: @Valorum https://i.imgur.com/x0A4w8k.png

Comment: @Darren you say that like it's a bad thing.